# Query Google App Engine Datastore with Key.Id

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa

I'm deploying a simple Java app to Google App Engine.

I have a simple JPA Entity containing a Key as my generated ID.

```
import javax.persistence.*;    

@Entity
public class MyEntity
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)    
    private com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key key;
...
```

Once I persisted this object. I can view the key's ID like so...

```
long id = entity.getKey().getId();
```

Do you know how I can I use the same Id to get my entity back? Something like this...

```
Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT e FROM MyEntity e WHERE e.key.id = :myId");
query.setParameter("myId", id);
```

The above doesn't work. I know I can get it back by passing in the Key as the parameter, but I'd like to know if I could use the long id instead.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Found the solution, create a Key using the KeyFactory and pass in the ID. Then Query on Key.

```
Key key = KeyFactory.createKey(MyEntity.class.getSimpleName(), id);
```

Comment: It is important to remember when using this method that the `id` passed in must be of type `Long`.

Comment: Any other method for using with `String` id ?

Answer (score 5):

There's no need to do a query at all, as the datastore natively supports fetching an entity by its key, which is substantially faster than doing a query. See [this section](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/creatinggettinganddeletingdata.html#Getting_an_Object_By_Key) of the docs.

Comment: Can you help provide a JPA example of this? It looks like PersistenceManager is only for JDO.

Comment: JPA is documented here: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/usingjpa.html

Comment: Thanks Nick, unfortunately that page doesn't tell me how to do a fetch with its key without using a query.

Answer (score 0):

You probably figured this out ages ago, but for others' benefit, this is how I do it in JPA:

```
entityManager.find(Reply.class, key)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the datastore developer's admin console, you can say something like:

`SELECT * FROM MyEntity WHERE __key__ = Key(MyEntity, 5695872079757312)`